# Unable to hear caller when using native internet (SIP) calling on Jelly Bean

Tags: voip, sip

I am using the native internet calling feature provided on Jelly Bean. (I believe this feature has been available since Gingerbread.)  I can make outgoing calls without issue.  Since my SIP account is connected to a PSTN (i.e. phone number) I can also receive calls.  However, when I answer an incoming call the calling party can hear me, but I cannot hear the caller on the other end.

My guess is that this is some kind of NAT problem.  See [here](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/FAQ#The_other_party_can_hear_me_but_I_can_not_hear_them), for example.  With other third-party SIP apps it is possible to use STUN to eliminate the problem. I don't see any corresponding options for the native SIP interface, though.  So I have two related questions:

**1. Is it possible to enable/use STUN with native internet calling?**

**2. How can I troubleshoot problems with native internet calling?**